# Remove a UITextView from a view

Tags: xamarin, uitextview

I have an iOS Xamarin View with a number of uitextview controls on, however depending on a setting I want to hide one or more the controls and move some up.

I have tried .hidden = true; which does hide the control but leaves the white space there. So looking to see how to get rid properly or be able to move fields

e.g Rows of UITextViews
Age
Name
Address

Lets say I want to not display Age, so I then want to move everything up so Name appears where Age would have been .

Answer (score 0):

Typical, I'm looking for X and Y relating to layout and stumble across Center, so try it.

Name.Center = Age.Center;

Comment: Worked for me since it needs to change depending on a setting when opening.

Comment: Ok, then you can mark this answer as the right answer which will help more people with same problem:).